# Animate Height for list items

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height

i have this code to animate Height:

```
$(".color_list").each(function() {  
    oHeight = $(this).height();
    $('.show_color').toggle(function(){
        $(this).parent('.color_list').addClass('open').animate({height:oHeight},200);   
        $(this).delay(200).css({'bottom':5});
        return false;
    },function(){
            $(this).parent('.color_list').removeClass('open').animate({height:112},200);
            $(this).delay(200).css({'bottom':0});
            return false;
    });
    if ($(this).height() > 120) {
        $(this).css({'height':112});
        $(this).children('.show_color').css({'display':'block'});
    }

});
```

In Firefox it works, but in Safari and Chrome it only works sometimes has anyone an idea why? 
Click on "more colors"

[here](http://haupt1.ohost.de/zipups/color/)

Comment: works for me. Which chrome version are you using?

Comment: It happends that "more colors" doesnt show at all and all colors are visible (MAc - Chrome current)

Comment: Funny, for me it works in Chrome but not in FF